# Seeking implementation of friend-selector type capability without invite/request

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I may be mistaken, but it appears that Facebook only supports friend-selector dialogs within a request/invite form. I take that to mean that since our app is just allowing the user to arrange a subset of friends for display within the app (no message to the friend), we must use something that isn't available from Facebook. It would be nice to know if I'm wrong, but important to have some clear pointers on how to get a friend ID back from the dialog without an invite or request getting sent to the friend.

I've searched for solutions and the closest I've come is a description of something that implements what I want offered for license by [Mike Knoop](http://knoopgroup.org/web-applications#friend-selector). I've tried making contact, but still don't know whether the code (or license terms) will work. It would be really nice to have a solution that was more open, but any pointers to widgets/libraries that include this capability would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the complete friend list of a user using the graph api and play with it as you wish:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/

Comment: Certainly a true statement. The question was about the implementation of a dialog analogous to the friend-selector. It seems that the legacy (server-based) FBML would allow a friend-selector without generating an invite/request but there's no such capability in XFBML.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that once you have all the friends, you can generate a friend selector for yourself. You can write the HTML needed and iterate over the friends to display them there. As far as I know, facebook doesn't give an out of the box solution for this.

Comment: I see that Facebook isn't providing support for this. I still hold out hope that someone in the community can identify a working implementation. Building the friend-selector isn't the way I was planning to spend my day.